# Minimal order of a set of permutations

Tags: permutations

We say that the *order* of a permutation $\sigma$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $\sigma^k$ is the identity permutation. That is, we repeatedly apply $\sigma$ until we get the identity permutation.

Suppose I have a set $S$ of permutations, all on the integers $[0, n)$. I am wondering what the *minimal order possible* for such a set is. By that I mean the smallest $k$ such that there exists a composition of $k$ permutations (allowing duplicates) from $S$ which forms the identity permutation.

An upper bound on this property is $\min_i \operatorname{order}(S_i)$. However, we can do much better. Consider $S = \{\sigma, \sigma^{-1}\}$, which would have $k = 2$ even if $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ themselves have a much larger order.

Is there a well-known name for this property of a set of permutations? An algorithm for computing it? Better known bounds?

Comment: The identity permutation has order $1$ which is minimal.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes, if the identity permutation is in $S$ we trivially have that the minimal order of the set is $1$. But the identity permutation might not be in $S$.

Comment: If $S$ is a generating set then this is the word problem for groups and is undecidable even if we only consider finite $S$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I fail to see how it is undecidable. It is certainly decidable to see whether a permutation of $[0, n)$ is the identity: try all $n!$ inputs. We know the upper bound on k is $\min_i \operatorname{order}(S_i)$. Thus we can enumerate all $k$-products of $S$ for all $k$ up to that upper bound, and for each check if it's the identity permutation, giving a guaranteed terminating correct algorithm.

Comment: You should clarify that you mean $[0,n)$ to be natural number as it's different than the symmetric group on the real interval $[0,n)$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField My bad, I have edited that in.